# I m trying to remove the data after adding search bar in tableview . but not able to do

Tags: ios

1. // here is my code

   ```
         class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate
         {

              @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
              @IBOutlet weak var tblview: UITableView!


         // here is array 

             var nameList = ["Superman","Ironman","Hulk","Spiderman","Batman","Captian America"]
             var filterdata = [String]()
   ```
2. // tableview method

   ```
                  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
                      cell.lblName.text = filterdata[indexPath.row]
                      cell.btnClear.tag = indexPath.row
                      cell.btnClear.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearaction), for: .touchUpInside)
                      return cell
                  }
   ```
3. // her is objective function

   ```
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText:
           String) {
                           filterdata = []
                           if searchText == "" {
                               filterdata = nameList
                           }

                           else {               
                               for items in nameList {
                                   if items.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                                       filterdata.append(items)
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                            self.tblview.reloadData(                }
   ```
4. // here is objective fucntion of clear data

   ```
                     @objc func clearaction(sender:UIButton) {
                        filterdata = nameList
                        nameList.remove(at: sender.tag)
                        tblview.reloadData()
   ```

Comment: The question needs more information. For example where is `clearaction` triggered?

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.lblName.text = filterdata[indexPath.row]
        cell.btnClear.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnClear.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearaction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

Comment: it is in tableview cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use this action code, you need to reload after delete and filter data.

@objc func clearaction(sender: UIButton) {
        if let index = nameList.firstIndex(of: filterdata[sender.tag]) {
            nameList.remove(at: index)
        }
        let searchText = searchBar.text ?? ""
        filterdata = nameList.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) })
        tblview.reloadData()
    }
```